# How to haccess routes all request for css/js to combine.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is my current `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I want to route all request for `js/css` to combine.php(for minyfying), so I Tried,

**Trial 1**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) /library/combine.lib.php?type=css&files=$1
RewriteRule ^js/(.*\.js) /library/combine.lib.php?type=javascript&files=$1
```

> Error : All request(css/js) are routed to index.php

**Trial 2**

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) /library/combine.lib.php?type=css&files=$1
 RewriteRule ^js/(.*\.js) /library/combine.lib.php?type=javascript&files=$1
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

> Error: 500 internal server error

How to accomplish all **request(js/css)** to go to `combine.php`, without disturbing the existing rewrite rules ?

Comment: Does **/css/foo.css** file exist on your server?

Comment: yup @Starkeen they do exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
 RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css)$ /library/combine.lib.php?type=css&files=$1 [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^js/(.*\.js)$ /library/combine.lib.php?type=javascript&files=$1 [NC,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still no luck ..all css /js request hitting index.php

Comment: What is the url your typing in your browser?

Comment: myurl/css/reset.css it taking me to index.php, it seems rewrite is working but when its going to requesting for combine.php, its being routed to index.php

Comment: Does this url 

www.example.com/library/combine.lib.php?type=css&files=reset.css  work when you enter it in browser?

Comment: it worked bro , my bad .. I  gave this <FilesMatch "^(combine\.php)?$">
    Allow from All
</FilesMatch>